# Google BigQuery ExtractBytesPerDay usage quota exceeded - What is ExtractBytesPerDay?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, quota

I am running a sequence of queries in BigQuery that take data from a table, enrich/transform them and load into other tables within the same project.

Very high level query structure looks as such:

```
WITH query_1 as (
SELECT columns from Table_A
WHERE some_condition = some_value
),
query_2 as (
SELECT processing_function(columns)
from A)
SELECT * from query_2
```

I am calling this query through Python and specifying the destination table in the query job config.

The Table_A mentioned above has about 2 TB of data for a day and I am looping this operation for 10 days. After processing just 1 day of data, BigQuery gave the following error

**403 Quota exceeded: Your usage exceeded quota for ExtractBytesPerDay.** For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

I checked the quota and it is pushing the 10TB quota limit I have but I'm not able to figure out what ExtractBytesPerDay quota really is. I can increase the quota limit, but I would like to evaluate how much I would need to increase it.

So any direction on which operations account for this quota would be helpful.  Anybody know what ExtractBytesPerDay quota means??

Answer (score 0):

You quota seems to be related to [Exporting Data from BQ](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_stored_in) that extract data to a destination like Cloud Storage.

You should know that there is a new API called [BigQuery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/) that  can help to mitigate your quota issue.

In case that don't help you, you might want to contact the [Google Cloud Platform Support](https://cloud.google.com/support#support-plans) to get more insights and know how to resolve your error.